# spring boot failed to start with error ClassUtils.isLambdaClass not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Spring-boot-2.7.4, java17 application failed to start with below error, Help me to fix the issue.
commons-io downloading from POI jar(poi-ooxml version 5.3.2), also we need spring-aop jar too.

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:448)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
'boolean org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isLambdaClass(java.lang.Class)'
```

The calling method's class, org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.3.29/spring-aop-5.3.29.jar!/org/springframework/aop/framework/autoproxy/AbstractAutoProxyCreator.class
jar:file:/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0/commons-io-2.11.0.jar!/org/springframework/aop/framework/autoproxy/AbstractAutoProxyCreator.class
```

The calling method's class was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.3.29/spring-aop-5.3.29.jar
```

The called method's class, org.springframework.util.ClassUtils, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0/commons-io-2.11.0.jar!/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.class
jar:file:/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.29/spring-core-5.3.29.jar!/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.class
```

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
org.springframework.util.ClassUtils: file:/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0/commons-io-2.11.0.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator and org.springframework.util.ClassUtils

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: If you get these errors this means you are doing too much dependency management. Post your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Where has your `commons-io-2.11.0.jar` file come from? It appears to contain Spring Framework classes but [the artifact on Maven Central](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0/commons-io-2.11.0.jar) does not.

Comment: @M.Deinum Did not get you that what is too much dependency Management?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson commons-io downloading part of POI dependency which we need for Excel use cases. I can't add the screenshot here but I can see with the help of Intellij that some spring packages inside it.

Comment: @KarkalaSrikanth I wouldn't trust that jar as it's not the one published by the project itself to Maven Central. If you look in `.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0/_remote.repositories` it should tell you from where the jar, pom, and source was downloaded.

Comment: You get these kinds of errors if you are mixing versions from different modules of spring of versions of the same module.. Which is generally due to bad dependency management or trying to outsmart the already smart Spring Boot Starter and parent dependency management. Hence we want to see your pom.